# How to rerender apex:form when action invoking from apex:page... please comment

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" controller="ContinuationController" action="{!startRequest}">  

<apex:form id="result"> <br /><br /> 

 <apex:pageBlock > 
 <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" > 
 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
 <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!doclist != null}"> <center> <b> Documents Details </b></center> <br /> <br />
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!doclist}" var="cwl" >   <!--   -->
  <Apex:column >
   <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!cwl.bselected}"/>  
  </Apex:column>
   <Apex:column value="{!cwl.DocType}" headervalue="Document Name"/> 
   <Apex:column value="{!cwl.DocURL}" headervalue="Document Link"/> 
  </apex:pageBlockTable> 
 </apex:outputPanel> 
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection> 
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. The page will be rendered after the action has finished thus taking into account the processing that the action performed.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link [Order of Execution for Visualforce Page Get Requests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_get_request.htm)

Basically if your **doclist** is populated in the controller constructor, you should get the output. If your requirement is different, try shifting your code in/out of controller.. it's not appropriate to rerender on page load (kind of deadlock situation).

I hope above information will help you.